# dropdown menu OracleJet / Javascript

Tags: javascript, oracle-jet

Im trying to implement dropdown menu in oracle JET but if I click on the menu link it doesn't work :( What am I doing wrong?

html:

```
<div id='menubutton-container'>
<oj-menu id="myMenu" slot="menu" style="display:none" on-oj-action="[[menuItemAction]]">
<oj-option id="ac" value="Additional Compensation" >
    <span class="demo-icon-font demo-fire-icon-24" slot="startIcon"></span>
    <a id="1ds" href="#2"
       data-bind="click: menuItemAction">MyLink</a>
</oj-menu>
</oj-menu-button>
</div>
```

vieModel js:

```
self.selectedMenuItem = ko.observable("(None selected yet)");
self.menuItemAction = function( data, event )
{
    this.selectedMenuItem(event.currentTarget.id);
    return true;
};
Bootstrap.whenDocumentReady().then(
    function()
    {
        ko.applyBindings(new EmployeesViewModel, document.getElementById('menubutton-container'));
    }
);
```

Comment: where is oj-menu-button starting tag

Comment: What is the action you want to happen? Right now you're simply updating selectedMenuItem, so you won't see anything visually

Answer (score 0):

First there is no closing tag for oj-option and starting tag for oj-menu-button.
The currentTarget.id it will refer to oj-menu.

below html and js  works fine

```
  <div id='menubutton-container'>
  <oj-menu-button>      
      <oj-menu id="myMenu" slot="menu" style="display:none" on-oj-action="[[menuItemAction]]">
          <oj-option id="ac" value="Additional Compensation" >
              <span class="demo-icon-font demo-fire-icon-24" slot="startIcon">MyLink</span>
          </oj-option>  
      </oj-menu>
  </oj-menu-button>
```

```
            self.selectedMenuItem = ko.observable("(None selected yet)");
            self.menuItemAction = function (event)
            {
                console.log(event.currentTarget);
                console.log(event.currentTarget.id);
                console.log(event.target.value);
                self.selectedMenuItem(event.target.value);
                return true;
            };
```